# nginx+php-fpm Warning Not Disappear

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

In my `php.ini`

```
error_reporting  = E_ERROR ^ E_WARNING
```

In my scripts:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
```

In my `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
php_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

But still Warnings like this are shown:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant xxx - assumed 'xxx' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in yyyyyyyyxxxxxx on line 7
```

Comment: Fix the warning, not the reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Basically, there is an hint in the conf template of php-fpm:

```
; Default Value: nothing is defined by default except the values in php.ini and
;                specified at startup with the -d argument
;php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f www@my.domain.com
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
```

Therefore, the solution is to switch off the error reporting of `php-fpm` and accept the php.ini settings. In your `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`:

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
```